# Split 2nd occurrence of pattern of camel style text in sed

Tags: macos, awk, sed

I am trying to create a key, value strings table for a mac app using sed and awk. So far I have got it to the point of having lines like:

```
"exif:DateTimeOriginal" = "DateTimeOriginal:\t";
```

I want to do a final step to get:

```
"exif:DateTimeOriginal" = "Date Time Original:\t";
```

In other words split up the second occurrence of the camel text.
I have seen sed like this:

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/g'
```

Which would do it globally and then just do the 2nd occurrence with:

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/2g'
```

Or is it 3rd occurrence. However, unfortunately on macos you can't combine a number with the g command.

So is there another way to do this?

BTW, I could make it so that you start with:

```
"exif:DateTimeOriginal" = DateTimeOriginal:\t";
```

That is, leave out the leading quote of the camel text, so that if a leading space is added by splitting the camel text, it would be added after the = which wouldn't matter. Then add the leading quote after the camel text is split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it with sed:

```
sed -E -e ':a' -e 's/^([^=]+)= (.*)([a-z])([A-Z])/\1= \2\3 \4/' -e 'ta'
```

The idea is to apply repeated substitutions (`:a` and `ta`) where you match the part you don't want to change (`[^=]+`) and then insert a space between a lowercase letter followed by an upper case letter (`[a-z][A-Z]`) in the remainder.

Comment: I ended up using the inelegant method of temporary files as mentioned above, then merging the files with unix merge.

Comment: I should say, I used the Unix paste command: paste -d " " file1 file2 > outputFile.

Answer (score 1):

with `GNU` awk (not the default for your OS).

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='"' '{$4=gensub(/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/,"\\1 \\2","g",$4)}1' file

"exif:DateTimeOriginal" = "Date Time Original:\t";
```

you may need [:lower:] or [:upper:] char classes based on your locale.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into that. Another way might be to start with the original string which is: DateTimeOriginal, split that up and save it to a temporary file, Then merge it with the first part of the string: "exif:DateTimeOriginal" =.

Comment: @JimMerkel no, this is a trivial task, you don't need temp files to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

With any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {gsub(/[[:upper:]]/," &",$4); sub(/^ /,"",$4)} 1' file
"exif:DateTimeOriginal" = "Date Time Original:\t";
```

Comment: Thanks. It's trivial or not depending on how often you need to develop a script. I develop a script maybe every few months or so. I have to go back and RTFM to figure out how to write a script to do a particular thing.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;s/\B[[:upper:]]/ &/g;H;x;s/=.*=/=/' file
```

Make a copy of the current line.

Insert a space before all capitals within a word.

Append the result to the original line.

Remove the tail of the original line and the head of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ echo '"exif:DateTimeOriginal" = DateTimeOriginal:\t"' | perl -F'"' -lane ' $F[2]=~s/(?=[A-Z])/ /g;$F[2]=~s/\s+=\s+/=\"/g; print "\"$F[1]\"$F[2]\"" '
"exif:DateTimeOriginal"="Date Time Original:    "
$
```